# Is it possible to install and use Genesys 8.1 with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, compatibility, genesys

I tried to install Genesys 8.1 with SQL Server 2012. I have made the configuration but when I tried to start CME it says

> Configuration server cannot be found. Please check the host and port

In documentation I could see that for SQL Server 2008 and newer, it needs Genesys DB Server 8.1.2 or newer. But I only have a Genesys DB Server which is older than that.

Anything we can do to make Genesys work with the already existing resources with me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can with last 8.1 CfgServer and last DBServer.
For your issue you had to check DBServer logs and CfgServer logs

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. But for Ver 8.1 you need config server and DB server before building the rest framework. And also read logs for any issue